# Dividir texto en dos div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estoy haciendo una factura en JavaScript, PHP, HTML y CSS y me surge una duda. El diseño de la factura simula un folio al igual que lo hacen los editores de texto de escritorio. Eso lo he solucionado con `<page>` y CSS.

Al llegar el contenido a según qué línea crea otra página y duplica algunas div de cabecera y pie de página, pero las líneas de artículos continúan en la página 1 hasta el fin de los días saltándose la separación entre páginas, el pie de página y la cabecera de la siguiente página.

¿Cómo podría hacer para definir que el espacio de texto mide x y cuando exista otra página continue escribiendo en la siguiente página en el espacio destinado para tal?

El código que tengo que cuenta las lineas y crea la página nueva es este:

```
var Infactura_Lineanum = Contarlineas('#Lineas_Infactura'); 
if (Infactura_Lineanum >= 5) {
    ++Infactura_Pagina;
    var Infactura_Lineanum = 0;
    $('#doc_Infactura').append(
        '<page size="A4" id="Pagina'+Infactura_Pagina+'" class="insertarDoc">
        <div id="cabeceradoc">Factura</div><div class="logo"><img src="../Scripts/Imagenes/Empresas/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'];?>/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Logo'];?>" alt="<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Nombre'];?>" /></div><div class="marca_agua"><img src="../Scripts/Imagenes/Empresas/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'];?>/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_MarcaAgua'];?>" alt="<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Nombre'];?>" />&nbsp;</div><div class="Empresa"><?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Nombre'];?></div><div class="Registromercantil"><?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Registro'];?></div><div id="Infactura_Totales_'+Infactura_Pagina+'">&nbsp;</div><div class="Npagina">Pagina '+Infactura_Pagina+'</div>
        </page>'
    );
    $('#Infactura_Totales_1').appendTo('#Infactura_Totales_'+Infactura_Pagina);
```

Aquí se puede ver exactamente lo que pasa. Si os fijáis en la separación entre folios hay texto y en la parte superior del segundo folio debería dejar espacio para la cabecera.

No sé si se hace con CSS, con jQuery, o con PHP, ni cómo buscar en internet exactamente lo que necesito que seguro que hay mil soluciones, lo único que no sé exactamente cómo se dice lo que estoy buscando.

[image]

y otra duda ya que estamos.

Con el `.append` de jQuery, ¿no puedo insertar saltos de línea para que el código sea más limpio mientras programo?

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta el HTML que genera el script para facilitar la comprension ya que la solucion seguramente sea una combinacion de html + css

Comment: La estructura básica esta en el .append de jquery el codigo entero son un porron de lineas de con mil funciones y mil consultas a mysql... si os lo pongo entero moriréis de la pereza para entenderlo... a ver si puedo resumirlo un poco. Pero básicamente es una tabla ( que puedo cambiar a otra cosa si es necesario ) y cada linea de articulo es un tbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AL final lo he resuelto simplemente metiendo una capa con el espacio necesario.

al llegar a la linea que crea la nueva pagina he puesto esto:

```
$('#Lineas_Infactura').append('<div class="Espaciador">&nbsp;</div>');
```

y problema resuelto ya tengo mi espacio en blanco que necesito :) no se si sera la mejor opción y seguramente hay otras muchas mas elegantes, pero de momento funciona.

:)